# Ionic 3 Camera Plugin Crashed with saveToPhotoAlbum true on IPhone

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm working with Ionic 3 and I'm trying to take a picture and saved it directly into the Gallery.

It works fine for Android but it crashes with iPhone and when I turn saveToPhotoAlbum to false, it works fine, So I realized that the problem is with this option.

I'm using the Docs Code:

## home.ts:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
    }
    
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
     this.selectedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
```

In the Plugin's Docs, It is recommended to add those line to the:

## config.xml

```
</platform>

    <edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
    </edit-config>
```

Comment: Have u try normalizeURL for iOS ?

Comment: Can you post crash report here what you are getting in iOS ?